# Get last post on each room with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to be able to retrieve the last post made by a user, on every room in the application. However, with the query I've built, I is retrieving allways the first one?

The tables look like this

```
Rooms
id|name|subname 

Posts
id|title|description|id_room|date_posted
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

```
SELECT * FROM rooms AS rm
INNER JOIN posts AS pst ON pst.id_room = rm.id
WHERE pst.id = ( 
SELECT MAX( pst.id ) FROM posts ) 
GROUP BY rm.id
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain a little more of what the rest of your database and use case look like?

Comment: Just edited with table info

Comment: `SELECT pst.id_room, pst.id, max(date-posted) from posts pst group by pst.id_room, pst.id;` I think so this is what you need???

Comment: how is post.id generated? is it increasing? would it make sense to use the date to select instead?

Comment: both can be used as the id is auto incremented and non updatable

Comment: @Meherzad, your code doesn't work. I want the results sorted by room, and your solution doesn't have any link to it

Comment: SELECT pst.id_room, pst.id, max(pst.id) from posts pst group by pst.id_room, pst.id; Now check have changed the date..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like that should be better (your query just retrieve the MAX pst.id, not the MAX pst.id by room)

```
select * from rooms as rm
inner join posts as pst on pst.id_room = rm.id
where pst.id in (select max(pst.id) from posts
                 group by pst.id_room)
```

simplified [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0c1/6), with your query and mine.

Comment: It still returns the first post... and yes, I want the result for each room in the database table, hence the join

Comment: @JoãoDias see SqlFiddle in my answer, something's different from what you have ?

Comment: Yes I missed the IN statement. It works fine now. One issue thought, is that it takes 1 second to run the query. Couldn't it be any faster?

Comment: @JoãoDias edited again : SqlFiddle with your query and mine, you can clearly see the difference.

Comment: Of course, to beat the odd corner case, it would be better to order posts by `date_posted` and then by `id`